# Protection from tree-stumps

Tags: pali-canon

In the [Paritta Parikamma](http://www.softerviews.org/AIM/parikamma.html), there is the line:

> May you take care in protecting yourselves from the dangers of tyrants, robbers, human beings, non-human beings, fires, floods, demons, **tree-stumps**, thorns, evil planets, epidemics, wrong-doers or heretics; from wild elephants, horses, beasts, oxen, dogs, serpents, scorpions, poisonous snakes, leopards, bears, hyenas, boars, buffaloes, ogres, devils etc., and from dangers of various fears, diseases and disasters.

- What dangers would tree-stumps pose?
- What would protection from tree-stumps look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Protection from tree-stumps

*Santa100* already gave an answer from a historic perspective.
Here is an answer from a modern perspective. The dangers and solution seem to still be the same.

> What dangers would tree-stumps pose?

According to [*"Dangers of Tree Stumps – Land Owners’ Responsibilities"*](http://www.treestumpsremoval.co.uk/news/dangers-of-tree-stumps-land-owners-roles-and-responsibilities), the dangers are: *constant tripping hazard, the stump harbouring insects, equipment damage*.

> What would protection from tree-stumps look like?

The solution would be to remove the stump by oneself or hire a professional stump remover.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine if you were a good old villager in 5 B.C India walking barefoot on the field at night, then yeah, tree-stumps and thorns could pose some real danger to your feet! And how would protection from tree-stumps look like? Well, as the very first phrase has said: "May you take care in protecting yourselves...".

Comment: It's not different today for those not wearing shoes and do or not care where to step. At least good imagined. And what is care for one self? Sila, metta. Even with shoes stumps can be "reason" for broken leg, ...even death. They nevertheless would listen to modern...